# remote multiple raspberry pi using ssh without password

Tags: ssh, password, multiboot

I using
 `for i in <ip1> <ip2> ... <ipn>; do ssh pi@$ip sudo halt; done` 
to turn off multiple raspberry pi. But i don't want iput password one by one for a lot of raspberry pi. So what should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not Raspberry-specific.

Read up ssh **key-based authentication** as put e.g. [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server)

As soon you have the shared key created and copied it onto the target hosts (simplest method: use **ssh-copy-id**), you can start an **ssh agent** on the coordinating host (e.g. in its .profile or .xinitrc) and only need to type the key password once per session with **ssh-add**.

Or use passwordless keys.

Comment: ... and if I may add: check out Steve Robillard's series on the topic on our blog: [SSH Security and Usability – Part 1 (and follow-ups)](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148032481829).